# Easily read and write XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have already found something for reading XML, however I find it difficult to write and update XML.

Can anybody please help in giving some code or advice on the best way of writing to XML files?

Comment: What .Net Framework do you use?

Comment: I am using 3.5 framework

Answer (score 8):

Use **[LINQ to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)**.

Based on the fact you're using **.NET 3.5**, LINQ to XML makes life so much easier when working with XML. Reading, writing, and amending XML documents via LINQ is a breeze. The link I posted is just a quick overview, but it should at least give you a taste of what it's like.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to check out the Linq-XML questions here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq-to-xml

Answer (score 1):

Load it up in an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) first. Also see the link for more information and examples.